# Yii2 Gridview left Join Inverse

Tags: php, yii2

Estoy usando [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) para hacer una consulta:

```
Usuarios
------------
juan
pedro
oscar

Tarjetas
------------
juan 123
pedro 987
oscar 657
oscar 987
```

Es decir tengo menos *usuarios* que *tarjetas*, uno tiene 2 tarjetas. Si yo hago esta consulta:

```
select * from Usuarios leftJoin Tarjetas On idusuario = idUsuarioTarjeta
```

Me devuelve todo; es decir:

```
juan 123
pedro 987
oscar 657
oscar 987
```

Pero si hago eso mismo en `yii2` ya con las relaciones en los modelos y todo:

```
find()->joinwith('tarjetas');
```

El `gridview` solo devuelve esto:

```
juan 123
pedro 987
oscar 657
```

Si hago un `find()->joinwith('tarjetas')->select('nombreUsuario, interbancariaCuenta');` obtengo como lo quiero, pero el `gridview` ya no reconoce los valores de tarjetas, es decir, el gridview ya no reconoce `tarjetas.interbancariaCuenta`.

Ya cambié la relación de `hasMany` a `hasOne`, pero igual:

```
juan  nodefinido
pedro nodefinido
oscar nodefinido
oscar nodefinido
```

Yo se que puedo hacer la busqueda no invertida si no, tarjetas->joinleft a *Usuarios*, y tendríamos lo que quiero hacer, pero como pienso unirlo con otras tablas, ocupo el invertido para que me arroje *`n`* cantidad de veces los usuarios y cada una de las cuentas o tarjetas.

Cabe destacar que si hago un *`select`* directo en mysql lo hace sin ningún problema y me da todos los valores que quiero, solo es el tema con el yii2

¿Cómo puedo resolver esta situación?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno igual siempre me respondo solo...

Como no consegui hacerlo mediante los modelos de yii. simplemente use un sqlDataProvider a mano.

```
$totalCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE publish=:publish', [':publish' => 1])
            ->queryScalar();

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE publish=:publish',
    'params' => [':publish' => 1],
    'totalCount' => $totalCount,
    //'sort' =>false, to remove the table header sorting
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'title' => [
                'asc' => ['title' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['title' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Post Title',
            ],
            'author' => [
                'asc' => ['author' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['author' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Name',
            ],
            'created_on'
        ],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Aldo, El select de tu dataProvider no tiene nada que ver, con las tablas usuarios  y tarjetas. Hace una consulta a la tabla posts.

Comment: No amigo, el codigo que puse abajo solo fue el ejemplo de como lo resolvi, es decir hice mi propio dataprovider sin usar el searchmodel, se me hace una manera sucia de programar teniendo el framework pero no encontre la respuesta.